# Trying to work around unbound local error

Tags: pyscripter

I have seen this question popping in many places but so far I cannot find the answer to why I keep getting the error.

I am defining a tool as follows:

```
def SumRasList (RasVar, Output):
    RasList = arcpy.ListRasters(RasVar, "TIF")
    print RasList
    i = 0
    for Ras in RasList:
        Rasters = Raster(Ras)
        if i == 0:
            OutRas = Rasters
            i += 1
        else:
            OutRas = OutRas + Rasters
    OutRas.save(Output)
```

The error tells me that OutRas is referenced before assignment.

Hopefully that is enough for any of you helping hands to see what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is one of scoping. The first time it goes through the first branch, and then the second time into the second branch but has no idea about the scope of the first branch.

The easy solution is to deal with this before introducing the branch.

```
from arcpy import ListRasters, Raster


def sum_ras_list(pattern, output):
    ras_list = ListRasters(pattern, "TIF")

    if not ras_list or not len(ras_list):
        print("You found no data")
        return

    # Work with the first piece of data
    out = Raster(ras_list.pop(0))

    # Work with the rest of the data
    for ras in ras_list:
        out = out + Raster(ras)
        out.save(output)
```